# I want to mirror two external hard drives

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, raid

We're pulling a bunch of things (GBs) off of our network storage and archiving it onto external HDDs.  Copies are made of each external HDD so that one can go off-site and one can stay here.  Is there a way to mirror the two drives (RAID 1?) and copy the data to both at the same time?

Comment: Sans Digital makes some nice small raid enclosures, high quality, been using one for 5 years, very happy with it...http://www.sansdigital.com/mobilestor/index.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest you just roll with a simple rsync script for this. Nice thing about not going RAID is then you don't have to worry about the particular RAID implementation you elect actually handles a missing disk... Granted that should work okay anyway..

Comment: +1 for not having to worry about the RAID implications.